# Can DynamoDB or SimpleDB replace my MongoDB use-case?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

I was wondering if DynamoDB or SimpleDB can replace my MongoDB use-case?  Here is how I use MongoDB

- 15k entries, and I add 200 entries per hour
- 15 columns each of which is indexed using (ensureIndex)
- Half of the columns are integers, the others are text fields (which basically have no more than 10 unique values)
- I run about 10k DB reads per hour, and they are super fast with MongoDB right now.  It's an online dating site.  So the average Mongo query is doing a range search on 2 of the columns (e.g. age and height), and "IN" search for about 4 columns (e.g. ethnicity is A, B, or C... religion is A, B, ro C).
- I use limit and skip very frequently (e.g. get me the first 40 entries, the next 40 entries, etc)
- I use perl to read/write

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming you're asking because you want to migrate directly to an AWS hosted persistence solution? Both DynamoDB and SimpleDB are k/v stores and therefor will not be a "drop-in" replacement for a document store such as MongoDB.

With the exception of the limit/skip one (which require a more k/v compatible approach) all your functional requirements can easily be met by either of the two solutions you mentioned (although DynamoDB in my opinion is the better option) but that's not going to be the main issue. The main issue is going to be to move from a document store, especially one with extensive query capabilities, to a k/v store. You will need to rework your schema, rethink your indexes, work within the constraints of a k/v store, make use of the benefits of a k/v store, etc.

Frankly if your current solution works and if MongoDB feels like a good functional fit I'd certainly not migrate unless you have very strong non-technical reasons to do so (such as, say, your boss wants you to ;) )

What would you say is the reason you're considering this move or are you just exploring whether or not it's possible in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the details!  Good question.  The main reason I'm considering moving to SimpleDB or DynamoDB is because since I will be moving to AWS anyways, it seems like it'll be easier to maintain.  From looking at the manuals for setting up MongoDB on AWS, it seems quite involved and expensive since I'll need at least 3 machines to host this.  Right now my prototype is on a single box, which is quite cheap and easy.  However, it seems like a production-ready setup would requires at least 3 machines and a good amount of setup work.

Comment: Depending on what you need, 1 machine might be plenty. If journaling + backups are "safe" enough for you, there's no reason to use a replica set.

That said, there are a few companies doing hosted MongoDB on top of Amazon. I work for one. :) It's much less work to let one of us handle things.

Comment: I've always found the setup of MongoDB relatively easy and setting up three boxes on AWS is done in a matter of minutes. For prototypes a single box will do fine and if you move to production is a few hours spent on cluster setup really a factor in the big picture? In terms of cost I don't see the different solutions being that far apart. AWS' storage services are quite expensive if you run high throughput.

Comment: And as MrKurt said, there are MongoDB hosting wrappers on top of AWS ;)

Comment: Thanks again for the details!  This is certainly very helpful.  What plan would you reccomend through MongoHQ?  Does it backup to EBS in the event of some type of failure?

Comment: @RemonvanVliet: What all do I need? EBS, 3 large ec2 instances?  Are there any other services I need to subscribe to?  This is starting to sound expensive :(.

Comment: SimpleDB and DynamoDB are both document stores (where a row = a collection of k/v), in fact every attribute in SimpleDB is index and you have pretty good queriability with SimpleDB too (but limit to 25 comparisons per query). DynamoDB supports queries on the range keys but also supports table scanning, but since nothing's indexed so scanning a whole table is relatively slow.

Comment: @theburningmonk SimpleDB and DynamoDB are both (correctly) officially classified as key-value stores. That a value can be a document is certainly true but that does not make it a document database conceptually (meaning, it's elementary units of data are documents).

Comment: @Zenorilnc You need 1 or 3 instances, EBS is optional but certainly recommended. The size of the instances depend on load but if you need 3 large ones for your load it's not going to be (much more) expensive than the same types of load on DynamoDB or SimpleDB I would think. The only way to find out is to run projected load on all solutions and see where you're at. AWS is never going to be the cheapest options regardless.

Comment: @Zenorilnc You're not doing a huge amount, I'd just start with a "Small" plan on MongoHQ and move up as necessary. If you want a replica set, the small replica set plan would be more than enough (I think).

Answer (score 4):

If you are planning to have your complete application on AWS then you might also consider using Amazon RDS (hosted managed MySQL). It's not clear from your description if you actually need MongoDB's document model so considering only the querying capabilities RDS might come close to what you need.

Going with either SimpleDB or DynamoDB will most probably require you to rethink some of the features based around aggregation queries. As regards choosing between SimpleDB and DynamoDB there are many important differences, but I'd say that the most interesting ones from your point of view are:

1. SimpleDB indexes all attributes
2. there're lots of tips and tricks that you'll need to learn about SimpleDB (see [what the guys from Netflix learned while using SimpleDB](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/713200984/practical-tips-for-optimizing-simpledb-access))
3. DynamoDB pricing model is based on actual write/read operations (see my [notes about DynamoDB](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/16064274863/notes-about-amazon-dynamodb))